# jQuery: How do I restrict number of chars?

Tags: javascript, jquery, numbers

I am writing an application which generates a price for something. Lets say we get an output like this:

24543.66666667  €

What does the jQuery function need to look like for achieving the following format:

24.543,66   €

?

(please note that the dot in the first price needs to be replaced by a comma)

Comment: you want result in this format "24.543,66" or or "24,543.66" ??

Comment: edited answer to a better solution

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/) format

The formatting and rounding you asked can be done like this:

```
var nb = new Number(24543.6666667);
var result = Number(nb.toFixed(2)).toLocaleString("nl-NL");
```

check: http://jsfiddle.net/5A6q3/1/

note that i've used the Dutch locale because this locale is using the `,` and `.` signs as you wanted. This can be used with any locale you want though.